# Angular - $scope value disappear during $.post

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I have a problem with getting the value of array inside $.post result

```
$scope.number = [];
for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
  $scope.number.push(i)
}

console.log($scope.number.length); // this return 3
$.post('/path/to/api', function(data, status) {
  console.log($scope.number.length); // this return 0
  $.each($scope.number, function(index, val) {
    consol.log(val)
  });
}).fail(function() {
  console.log('error')
})
```

The $scope.number array value disappear when i want to use it on $.post. Is there something i'm missing here ?

(edit)
but when i try outside of the post value is back

```
 $scope.number = [];
for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
  $scope.number.push(i)
}

console.log($scope.number.length); // this return 3
$.post('/path/to/api', function(data, status) {

}).fail(function() {
  console.log('error')
})
console.log($scope.number.length) // this return 3
$.each($scope.number,function(key,val){
console.log(val);
})
```

Comment: Side note: Why aren't you using `$http`?

Comment: Nothing in code shown would cause that behavior. Provide a [mcve]

Comment: It's already added on controller module, so i just need to type $.post

Comment: consider adding `$timeout(function() { /* your code */ });` it usually fix alot of problem. Don't know why though. hahahaha

Comment: @Nicolas because it returns a promise, resolving an inner function asynchronously (with or without any delay added)